# Use different attribute and measure names for front end applications in SSAS

Tags: ssas

We are building an SSAS cube where our users have requested the names of our measures and attributes be something different to what we, as the developers, want to see.

Obviously the user's get to decide that the names will be, however they are names that make no sense to us and as such make it difficult for us to write MDX over the attribute names.

Is there a way to have names that are internal for whilst developing, but front end applications see different names?

I see there is translations- would it work if we set a translation for the English language to show the names how they want to see it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say developers and users both speak English. It's a clever trick to define an English translation for the data inside SSAS so that users see different measure and dimension names than developers do. This idea is described by Vidas Matelis [here](http://www.ssas-info.com/VidasMatelisBlog/37_customizing-object-names-in-analysis-services-database-using-translations).